# How to set image in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable, android-image

I want set `image` with programmatically and i should pass image into **constructor**. i use this code but when running application show me **Force Close**.

**Force Close error :**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: ir.mototel.mototel, PID: 12904
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
                      at com.sepandar.xengine.fragment.HomeFragment.newInstance(HomeFragment.java:60)
                      at com.sepandar.xengine.adapter.HomePagerAdapter.getItem(HomePagerAdapter.java:43)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:101)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1038)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1186)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1120)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:544)
                      at com.sepandar.xengine.fragment.MainFragment$1.onResponse(MainFragment.java:174)
                      at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

Initialize `imageView` and **setImage** in fragment :

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment {
private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";
public int categoy;
@Bind(R.id.recyclerView)
RecyclerView recyclerView;
@Bind(R.id.testFragmentImageID)
ImageView fragmentImage;
private HomeAdapter homeAdapter;
private Gson gson;
private ArrayList<Content> slider = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<TopChart> topCharts = new ArrayList<>();


public static HomeFragment newInstance(int position, ArrayList<TopChart> topChartsArray, int imageINT) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    HomeFragment instance = new HomeFragment();
    instance.categoy = position;
    instance.topCharts.addAll(topChartsArray);
    instance.fragmentImage.setImageResource(imageINT);
    instance.setArguments(bundle);
    return instance;
}

public static String getTAG() {
    return TAG;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    gson = new Gson();
    homeAdapter = new HomeAdapter(context, activity, categoy);
    homeAdapter.setCategories(topCharts);
    homeAdapter.updateItems();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

How can i fix this problem?

I know this error for **nullPointerExaption**, but how can i fix it?

Comment: You haven't shown implementation for HomeFragment. The fragmentImage object is null, you have to check how you set it.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, please see my update post. i initialize imageview

Comment: Can you add onCreateView() code

Comment: @subrahmanyamboyapati, please see my update post

Comment: Hey are you using butterknife 8.X ?

Comment: @subrahmanyamboyapati, no i use 7.0.1

Comment: @subrahmanyamboyapati, can you help me?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, can you help me?

Comment: You never initialize fragmentImage to anything. Of course it is null then and will cause the exception.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, how can fix this? please help me

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, i initialize imageView in HomeFragment and i use ButterKnife

Comment: Where do you initialize it? At least not in this code I can't see anything

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, i initialize this in **HomeFragment** :  `@Bind(R.id.testFragmentImageID)
 ImageView fragmentImage;`

Comment: Before calling onCreateView() you are trying to set image to ImageView, that's why you are getting nullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

This is happened to me. To solve this try below steps

1. Add below dependency in project `build.gradle`

   ```
   dependencies {
         classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
   }
   ```
2. Add below dependency to app `build.gradle` file

   `apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'`

   `dependencies {
        apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
   }`